# Java Docker clients for save/load and import/export commands

Tags: java, docker

Is there any Docker client that handles export/import and save/load options from JVM. I've been searching through Spotify's client as well as Java Docker API client but didn't find those commands. Any suggestions there?

Comment: You almost never need either pair of commands (save/load only if you're deploying into an off-the-network environment, export/import basically never at all).  Do you have a more specific use case that needs them?  `docker-java` for example does seem to include a [SaveImageCmd](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/docker-java-api/src/main/java/com/github/dockerjava/api/command/SaveImageCmd.java).

Comment: The thing is I want to experiment with these two pair of commands, later I will pick either first or second.

Comment: You probably want neither.  In most cases `docker push`, `pull`, and `run` should cover all of your needs (again, unless you're in that disconnected-network state).

Comment: There are some limitation in project I'm working on that we want to solve with exporting images as .tar, so I do need them